# stop sorting the sheetname from excel in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, sorting

I get the sheet Names from excel and create the buttons whose text is the sheet's name.

But every time the buttons are created they are sorted alphabetically. I don't want to sort them.

Here is my code :

```
    Dim objConn As OleDbConnection = Nothing
    Dim dt As System.Data.DataTable = Nothing

    Try

        Dim connString As String = ""

        If Extension = "xls" Or Extension = ".xls" Then

            connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & FileUploadPath & sender.text & ";Extended Properties=" + Convert.ToChar(34).ToString() + "Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1" + Convert.ToChar(34).ToString() + ""

        ElseIf Extension = "xlsx" Or Extension = ".xlsx" Then

            connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & FileUploadPath & sender.text & ";Extended Properties=" + Convert.ToChar(34).ToString() + "Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=2" + Convert.ToChar(34).ToString() + ""

        End If

        objConn = New OleDbConnection(connString)

        objConn.Open()

        dt = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)

        If Not dt Is Nothing Then

            Dim i As Integer = 1

            For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                Dim btn As Button = New Button
                btn.ID = "btnSheet" & i
                btn.Text = row("TABLE_NAME").ToString().Substring(0, row("TABLE_NAME").ToString.Length - 1)
                excelSheetButtonsList.Add(btn)
                tdInfo.Controls.Add(btn)
                tdInfo.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("&nbsp;"))
                AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf ExcelSheetNameButtons_Click
                i += 1
            Next

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally

        If objConn IsNot Nothing Then
            objConn.Close()
            objConn.Dispose()
        End If
        If dt IsNot Nothing Then
            dt.Dispose()
        End If

    End Try
```

The image 1 is the output of the above code :

[image]

Now the image 2 describes the excel sheet :

[image]

I want my output in the order as it is in image 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995984/get-index-of-the-excel-sheet-using-asp-net?rq=1) although that does not have a confirmed answer. See [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1783814.aspx/1) and refer to the accepted answer linked [here](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2011/12/upload-and-read-excel-file-in-aspnet.html)

Comment: I'm not full bottle but can you use an excel object to get them? This would preserve ordering.

Comment: @DavidZemens I have referenced the last link you provided and from there I got the code which is shown in the question. But there also sheet names are sorted.

Comment: @glh I think using excel object needs excel to be installed on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One (albeit not very reliable) way is to sort resulting DataTable (by creating a DataView based on it) sort it on DateCreated or DateModified columns.